# Strange behavior of go build with cmd/

Tags: go

Go build command doesn't create the same binary, it's wrong with cmd/ :
First ok (~/go/ empty before):

```
$ find .
.  
./cmd  
./cmd/api  
./cmd/api/main.go
```

I build :

```
$ cd cmd/api; go build -v main.go   
 get "gopkg.in/yaml.v2": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"gopkg.in/yaml.v2", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://gopkg.in/yaml.v2"} at //gopkg.in/yaml.v2?go-get=1   
 get "golang.org/x/sys": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/sys", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/sys"} at //golang.org/x/sys?go-get=1  
 get "gopkg.in/check.v1": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"gopkg.in/check.v1", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://gopkg.in/check.v1"} at //gopkg.in/check.v1?go-get=1  
 get "golang.org/x/text": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/text", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/text"} at //golang.org/x/text?go-get=1  
 get "golang.org/x/tools": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at //golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1   
 go: downloading github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.6.3   
 etc ....    
 go: finding golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20200116001909-b77594299b42
```

The result :

```
$ ls -l  
    total 14940   
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 fr3 nobody 15290667 May 12 14:00 main   
    -rw-r--r-- 1 fr3 nobody      619 May 12 13:41 main.go
```

And now with cmd/ :

```
$ find .
.  
./cmd   
./cmd/api  
./cmd/api/main.go
```

I use the mod command :

```
$ go mod init api  
go: creating new go.mod: module api   
$ go mod vendor   
go: finding github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.6.3   
go: downloading github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.6.3   
etc ....   
go: extracting github.com/go-playground/locales v0.13.0
```

vendor/ is created :

```
 ls -l   
 total 16   
  drwxr-xr-x 3 fr3 nobody 4096 May 12 13:42 cmd   
  -rw-r--r-- 1 fr3 nobody   61 May 12 14:07 go.mod  
  -rw-r--r-- 1 fr3 nobody 3872 May 12 14:07 go.sum   
  drwxr-xr-x 5 fr3 nobody 4096 May 12 14:07 vendor   
$ mkdir target  
 go build  -o target/api cmd/api   
$ ls -l target/
total 5912   
-rwxr-xr-x 1 fr3 nobody 6052601 May 12 14:08 api
```

[image: THE CODE]

Comment: **Do not post screenshots of text.** Just copy and paste the text into the body of the question.

Comment: I would like to do so but the site told me ~ "too much codes, add comments"

Comment: That means you're posting too much code and not enough explanation, which is probably also accurate. Your question/issue isn't very clear but I did my best to answer what you seem to be asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cd cmd/api; go build -v main.go
```

This is not how `go build` is used. `go build`, like most `go` commands, works with *packages*, not with *files*. So, you could:

```
cd cmd/api; go build -v .
```

Or, from the root of the project:

```
go build -v ./cmd/api
```

This will produce a binary named after the package, in the working directory. You can also use the `-o` flag (see the documentation) to choose the binary name and path you want output.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, it's ok.  So "./cmd/api" works but "cmd/api" does not !  So from now, I'll always use the dot-slash prefix. I just do not understand why go build wants this prefix because the relative directory is good. It could emit a warnig or refuse to produce a wrong binary.

Comment: Right at the start of the answer - "go build, like most go commands, works with packages, not with files". It's not a file path, it's not a directory path, *it's a package reference*. `cmd/api` is not a full package name. If you use `./cmd/api`, it looks for that package relative to the current directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this additional answer, it's clearer for me.

Answer (score 0):

From the Go documentation:

> When compiling a single main package, build writes the resulting executable to an output file named after the first source file ('go build ed.go rx.go' writes 'ed' or 'ed.exe') or the source code directory ('go build unix/sam' writes 'sam' or 'sam.exe'). The '.exe' suffix is added when writing a Windows executable.

Comment: I agree Jay, but here I've named the output file "api", so it's ok - but the size is exotic, and this second binary does'nt work, the first does

Comment: What's the error you're getting when you run the second binary?

Comment: a very very strange ouput ... after a while :   
``` 
pkg archive/tar, const FormatGNU = 8
pkg archive/tar, const FormatGNU Format
pkg archive/tar, const FormatPAX = 4
pkg archive/tar, const FormatPAX Format
pkg archive/tar, const FormatUSTAR = 2
pkg archive/tar, const FormatUSTAR Format
pkg archive/tar, const FormatUnknown = 0
pkg archive/tar, const FormatUnknown Format
etc ..... ```

Comment: You should also post some code then. What have you tried so far and what output you are expecting? The SO community will be able to help better that way.